# Someone please help me recover my data from localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, phpmyadmin

I have a server setup locally and is used by multiple employees. These employees enters data through a laravel website which is stored in my computer. I happened to use

> php artisan migrate:refresh

in that particular project. Now all the data worth investment of almost a year is gone. I would really appreciate if someone helped me recover the data.
I only have a backup of around 8 months ago.

Comment: it is not possible unless you keep backup of it

Comment: I only have a backup of around 8 months ago.

Comment: then only that u can restore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced this some time ago.
I also searched how to recover my lost data but unfortunately, I couldn't.
You can only recover if you backed up within that one year. Sorry man.

Comment: @Sourcerer I disagree. He is stating the answer is it cannot be done. That is a valid answer. A lack of examples and proof of something being possible is quite a valid argument that it is not possible. And with how data works it is generally the case that only backups can restore lost data.

Comment: It's only my opinion, but no problem I remove the comment.